# play a video with kivy: module 'ffmpeg' has no attribute 'FFVideo'

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to play a video into a kivy window, but I always have the same error, whatever the format of my video.

Here's my code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.video import Video

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        video = Video(source= # path)
        video.state='play'
        video.options = {'eos': 'loop'}
        video.allow_stretch=True
        return video

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

And the error is :

```
self._player = ffmpeg.FFVideo(self._filename)
AttributeError: module 'ffmpeg' has no attribute 'FFVideo'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

At the top of any import try to add:

```
import os
os.environ["KIVY_VIDEO"] = "ffpyplayer"
```

It solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it fixed now.

When I changed my Python Interpreter from 3.7 to Anaconda3 it works just fine.